# Cloudera HUE - HIVE not recognizing the Query

Tags: hadoop, hive, cloudera, hue

```
CREATE TABLE schema.table1 (
             DATE_OUT STRING COMMENT 'Date',
             STATUS_OUT STRING COMMENT 'Status',
             SHIP_NR_OUT STRING COMMENT 'Shipper Number',
             TABLE_NAME_OUT STRING COMMENT 'Table Name',
             AC_NR STRING COMMENT 'Account Number',
             AC_TYP_CD STRING COMMENT 'Account type code',
             CNY_CD STRING COMMENT 'Country code',
             AC_XCV_EMP_NR STRING COMMENT 'ACCOUNT EXECUTIVE EMPLOYEE NUMBER',
             ROW_UDT_TS STRING COMMENT 'ROW UPDATE INDICATOR')
COMMENT 'my desc' 
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.contrib.serde2.RegexSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
     "input.regex" = "(.{10})(.{1})(.{10})(.{7})(.{10})(.{2})(.{2})(.{9})(.{1})",
     "output.format.string" = "%1$s %2$s %3$s %4$s %5$s %6$s %7$s %8$s %9$s"
   );
LOCATION 'hdfs_path'
```

When I put it on the Screen, a 2nd screen comes up asking for parameters for this query? 
I am using HUE in CLOUDERA DISTRO where I see the message

Comment: The error disappeared when I took out the output.string.format. But this bugs me since it works if I do it in the CLI and not using HIVE?? Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parameter in your query is:

```
$s
```

If you use Hue you should uncheck 'Enable parametrization' in 'Settings' tab.

[image]